# Why Selenium don't run with InternetExplorer?

Tags: selenium

I write in Eclipse, but it doesn't run.

I don't know why.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
public class IEbrowser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver br = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        br.get("google.com");
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you tried to give path to the driver?

[driver link](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

after you download it in the program you need to give a full path:

```
string path = @"c:\driver\";

WebDriver br = new InternetExplorerDriver(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the path for the ie driver server.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","\path\to\IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Also selenium needs to set same security level for all zones.

1.Open IE

2.Go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Security

3.Set all zones to the same protected mode, enabled or disabled should not matter.

And also you need to set the zoom level of the page to 100%.

Comment: Please select the answer as correct answer if i answer your question.